# How to set value of React Material UI Slider via Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

I'm using slider from here: https://material-ui.com/components/slider/

Trying to set it's value like:

```
cy.get("[data-cy=slider-population]")
    .as("range")
    .invoke("val", val)
    .trigger("change");
```

However it's not moving. Anyone manage to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it a bit simpler for future viewers, @kevin's answer points you to all the right places to extract a working test, however here's everything without their demo code:

```
<Slider data-cy="slider-population" />
```

First, you need to add this command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("reactComponent", {
    prevSubject: "element"
}, ($el) => {
    if ($el.length !== 1) {
        throw new Error(`cy.component() requires element of length 1 but got ${$el.length}`);
    }
    // Query for key starting with __reactInternalInstance$ for React v16.x
    const key = Object.keys($el.get(0)).find((key) => key.startsWith("__reactFiber$"));
    const domFiber = $el.prop(key);
    Cypress.log({
        name: "component",
        consoleProps() {
            return {
                component: domFiber,
            };
        },
    });
    return domFiber.return;
});
```

Then in your test if you want to set the minimum to 0, and the max to 15:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="slider-population"]')
    .reactComponent()
    .its("memoizedProps")
    .invoke("onChange", null, [0, 15]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) which demonstrates this for it's purposes.

[`cy.setTransactionAmountRange`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts#L91-L101) is a command built to interact with the Material UI Slider.

It uses another Cypress custom command, [`cy.reactComponent`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts#L70-L89) to gain access to the component internals and allow methods like [`onChange` to be invoked directly on the component instance](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts#L100).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a spartan riff on the solution provided by Shannon Hochkins.

Usage:

```js
cy.get("[data-cy=slider-population]")
    .setSlider([0,15])
```

Command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setSlider', { prevSubject: 'element' },
    (subject, value) => {
        const key = Object.keys(subject.get(0))
            .find((key) =>
                key.startsWith("__reactFiber$"))
        const fiberNode = subject.prop(key)
        fiberNode.return.memoizedProps.onChange(null, value)
        return subject
    })
```

Typescript:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
        setSlider(value: number | number[]): Chainable<void>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution (cypress 12):

```
cy.dataCy("slider").within(() => {
    cy.get('[data-index="3"]').first().click();
});
```

(replace data-index with the index of the marker you wish to select - for discrete sliders only)